# Slide Down to normal width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I have a `div` box, with a lot of `p` tags in side, and it is getting very long.

So I added on the top of the box, a `show more` text.

The box have a `height: 100px; overflow: hidden;`, but then when someone click on `show more`, I would like it to `slideDown` the box, to get the normal `height`, which it would have had if `height: 100px;` was not set.

Any idea how to do this?

I tried the following: (Note, the box have class `.show-limited-content` and the `show more` have class `.show-more`)

```
$('.show-more').live("click", function() {
    $('.show-more').live("click", function() {
        $('.show-limited-content').slideDown("slow");
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

It would look something like the following, depending on how your html is written:

```
$('.show-more').on("click", function() {  
    $('.show-limited-content').animate({
        height: '500px'
      }, 2000);    
      return false;
  });
```

See [this](http://jsbin.com/amined/1/edit) working example to see it in action.

If you need the height dynamically, just add

```
var curHeight = $('.show-limited-content').height();

  $('.show-limited-content').css('height', 'auto');

  var autoHeight = $('.show-limited-content').height();

  $('.show-limited-content').height(curHeight);
```

above the event handler and change the animate css to

```
height: autoHeight
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/eyeyob/1/edit) is another example.

Comment: Thanks, but is there someway it can automatically find the height?

Comment: @ErikHansen Sure thing. Updated the answer and added a second example.